# Passing multiple parameters to the Element API

Tags: json, plugin-elementapi

How should I go about passing multiple parameters to the Element API?

The scenario is that I would like to display all my categories for a given section in a form, and allow the user to select categories, and send them to the API. I would like to receive back a json object of all the entries that have the categories assigned.

I am aware that I can dynamically catch url segments, but I'm not understanding how I would pass something like a GET parameter as a segment.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can fetch GET parameters using [HttpRequestService::getQuery()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/HttpRequestService#getQuery-detail) or [getRequiredQuery()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/HttpRequestService#getRequiredQuery-detail):

```php
'entries-by-category' => function() {
    $categoryIds = craft()->request->getRequiredQuery('categoryIds');

    return [
        'elementType' => 'Entry',
        'criteria' => [
            'relatedTo' => ['targetElement' => $categoryIds],
        ],
        // ...
    ];
},
```

Comment: Is there a way to require that the returned entries have all the categories assigned to them? With the code above it returns all entries that have at least one of the specified categories. (Should I be asking this as a new SE question?) Thanks!

Comment: Because I'm a little slow, can anyone provide an example of a full endpoint config using this method? I'm trying to do something similar but can't figure out how to implement this function.

Comment: @JesseSchutt (sorry just a little late here :) - yes, just set `'and'` as the first item in the `$categoryIds` array.

Comment: @anguiac7 that is the full endpoint config – `entries-by-category` is the endpoint’s URI pattern. If you need additional help it will probably be easier if you post as a new question.

Comment: @BrandonKelly ya know, that makes complete sense now. I made a new question [here](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/19165/elementapi-get-entries-with-category-that-has-category). I'll give it a shot now that I know that's the full config, though, and close the Q if that solves it.

Answer (score 1):

For those curious how to make sure that *all* categories match (`and` instead of `or`):

```
'entries-by-category' => function() {
    $categoryIds = craft()->request->getRequiredQuery('categoryIds');

    return [
        'elementType' => 'Entry',
        'criteria' => [
            'relatedTo' => ['targetElement' => ['and', 123, 234, 567]
        ],
        // ...
    ];
},
```

You can even have more related conditions going on and add the `and` relationship as well like that:

```
'entries-by-category' => function() {
    $categoryIds = craft()->request->getRequiredQuery('categoryIds');

    return [
        'elementType' => 'Entry',
        'criteria' => [
            'relatedTo' => [
                'and',
                ['targetElement' => ['and', 22, 33]],
                ['targetElement' => ['and', 123, 234]]
            ]
        ],
        // ...
    ];
},
```