# How can I use the ElementAPI to get related entries based on two parameters?

Tags: relations, plugin-elementapi

I can successfully get entries related the "normal" way, but my list of possible results are getting quite large. Currently I am returning html mixed in with the data. It's obvious I need to get just the data and parse through it on the client side.

**mytemplate.html**

```
{% set paramOne = craft.request.getParam('paramOne') %}
{% set paramTwo = craft.request.getParam('paramTwo') %}

{% set relationParam = ['and'] %}

{% if paramOne %}
    {% set type = craft.categories.group('groupOne').slug(paramOne).first() %}
    {% set relationParam = relationParam|merge([{ targetElement: type }]) %}
{% endif %}

{% if paramTwo %}
    {% set type = craft.categories.group('groupTwo').slug(paramTwo).first() %}
    {% set relationParam = relationParam|merge([{ targetElement: type }]) %}
{% endif %}

{% set entries = craft.entries.relatedTo(relationParam) %}
```

I'm not quite sure how to translate that into elementapi code (for lack of better words).

**elementapi.php**

```
return [
    'endpoints' => [
        'myfile.json' => function (??) {
            $paramOne = craft()->request->getPost('paramOne');
            $paramTwo = craft()->request->getPost('paramTwo');

            return [
                'elementType' => 'Entry',
                'criteria' => [
                    'section' => 'mysection',
                    'relatedTo' => [
                        'and' // and needs to go somewhere...
                        'targetElement' => ??, // This is the entry
                        'field' => ?? // This is the category?
                    ],
                ],
                'transformer' => function (EntryModel $entry) {
                    return [
                        'title' => $entry->title
                    ];
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
];
```

Comment: This question and the answers might help you out: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/11354/passing-multiple-parameters-to-the-element-api