# Use GET parameters to query for array of entry IDs

Tags: craft3, plugin-elementapi

On my client side, I have an array of entry IDs that match with entries in Craft

`const myIds = ['230', '249', '256']`

I am trying to send that array over to an Element API endpoint and use it in the `id` criteria to only grab entries with the specified IDs.

I am constructing my GET request and add `myIds` to the request parameters, then send it to the endpoint.

How would I access that array in parameters within `element-api.php`? I found a response for Craft 2 that looks like it's similar to what I want:
([Passing multiple parameters to the Element API](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/11354/passing-multiple-parameters-to-the-element-api)) which uses the `getQuery()` or `getRequiredQuery()` functions, but I'm not sure those still exist in Craft 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I found a response for Craft 2 that looks like it's similar to what I want: (Passing multiple parameters to the Element API) which uses the getQuery() or getRequiredQuery() functions, but I'm not sure those still exist in Craft 3?

In Craft 3, you'd use:

```
Craft::$app->getRequest()->getRequiredQueryParam('myArr')
```

https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-web-request.html#method-getrequiredqueryparam

Comment: I think I searched for "getQuery" in the v3 docs and didn't turn anything up, thanks a lot for that link, that's exactly what I need.